# Android Volley. Why is my response always being returned as false?

Tags: php, android

My PHP file, login.php, looks like this:

```
<?php

//if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
//$username = $_POST['username'];
$username = "Dave";
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($check)){
        echo 'Logged in';
} else {
        echo 'Could not log in';
}
//}

?>
```

When I go to myserver.com/login.php, I see `Logged in`, because Dave is in my database.

In my Android app, my Volley Log in button looks like this :

```
    private void userLogin() {
        username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
//        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.trim().equals("Logged in")){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"yahoo, you're in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            openProfile();
                        }else{
                              Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"sorry, you're out",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, etc... etc...
```

But when I click my Log in button, my toast is always, `sorry, you're out`. Do you know why ?

Comment: At the top of your PHP file add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and instead of using custom message for toasting you should simply toast the value of `response.trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because this:

```
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

The function returns an array (success) or boolean false (failure). Either way, `$check` is **ALWAYS** going to be set, so `isset($check)` will always return true.

Your logic should be

```
if ($check === false) {
```

which means there's no rows (or the query failed).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but changing if(isset($check)){ to if ($check === false) { didn't work.